# eclipse generates ._ files

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I get rid of the files that eclipse auto-generates?

I have plenty of entites and i now have 2 files, that pretty sucks. How can I remove the files that eclipse generates?

This is how they look like:

```
@Generated(value="Dali", date="2013-09-04T15:41:47.243+0200")
@StaticMetamodel(CompanyArea.class)
public class CompanyArea_ {
       public static volatile SingularAttribute<CompanyArea, Long> id;
       public static volatile SingularAttribute<CompanyArea, String> name;
       public static volatile SetAttribute<CompanyArea, Division> divisions;
}
```

Comment: Which "`._`" files? Can you please show the whole names? If you're asking about the JPA Criteria API, then those files are real Java classes that are necessary to make your program work and are actually being generated by your JPA provider.

Comment: Eclipse does not normally do that. Are you using a specific framework perhaps?

Comment: Check the "Java persistence" project properties. There must be a way to disable the Canonical Metamodel generation. Note that these generated classes are useful if you need to generate queries dynamically using the JPA criteria API.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys for your help.

I was yesterday in a rush, and as I read my question again today, I realized that I was not very specific.

Your answers helped figuring out the solution.

I just set the Canonical Metamodel source folder to  in the project properties - JPA.

Comment: Worked for me: Project > Properties > JPA > Canonical Model > Source Folder = None